# How to determine response data encoding in TIdHTTP?

Tags: delphi, http, character-encoding, delphi-xe5

I am new to HTTP. I have several HTTP GETs which return text encoded in either ANSI or UTF-8. Is there a way to determine which is returned so that I can handle the conversion in the method rather than doing trials and hard coding the necessary conversions for each? or if it can be handled by Indy itself?

Here's what I use to GET:

**Main Method**

```
procedure TIdHTTPHelper.SendGet
          ( const AURL     : String;
            var   AResponse: TMemoryStream );
begin

  Request.ContentType   := '';
  Request.ContentLength := -1;
  Get ( AURL, AResponse );
  AResponse.Position := 0;

end;
```

**Overloaded Method For Strings**

```
procedure TIdHTTPHelper.SendGet
          ( const AURL     : String;
            var   AResponse: String);
var
  Response : TMemoryStream;
begin

  Response      := TMemoryStream.Create;
  SendGet       ( AURL,          Response );
  SetLength     ( AResponse,     Response.Size div 2 );
  Response.Read ( AResponse [1], Response.Size );
  Response.Free;

end;
```

Comment: You should examine a `Charset` parameter for `Content-Type` header.

Comment: I had a similar question some time ago, I think that [Remy Lebeau's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18832982/800214) can help. Anyway, don't use TMemoryStream for Strings, use TStringStream

Comment: DON'T use `TStringStream`! In D2009+, it requires you to specify a `TEncoding`in the constructor, and you cannot change it afterwards. Unless you know the exact charset ahead of time, you can easily mismatch the encoding and cause a conversion failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TIdHTTP` has an overloaded version of `Get()` that returns a `String` (which is `UnicodeString` in D2009+ and `AnsiString` in earlier versions). It detects the response charset, even to go as far as parsing it from HTML and XML data when it is not present in the HTTP headers, and uses it to decode the response data to UTF-16 in D2009+ and Ansi in earlier versions for you:

```
procedure TIdHTTPHelper.SendGet
          ( const AURL     : String;
            var   AResponse: String);
begin
  AResponse :=  Get ( AURL );
end;
```

Have a look at this answer where I outlined the exact charset detection logic that `TIdHTTP` uses:

[TIdHTTP character encoding of POST response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18832081/tidhttp-character-encoding-of-post-response/18832982#18832982)

On a separate note, your other `SendGet()` method should not be taking a `TMemoryStream` by reference, since you are not returning a new `TMemoryStream` object to the caller. It should take a general `TStream` by value instead.  That would make your code much more flexible:

```
procedure TIdHTTPHelper.SendGet
          ( const AURL     : String;
            AResponse: TStream );
begin
  Get ( AURL, AResponse );
  AResponse.Position := 0;
end;
```